# How do I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}f(x)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose that a function $f(x)$ is defined as the sum of a series $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{(2!)^2}{(2015x)^2}+\frac{1}{(4!)^2}{(2015x)^4}-..........=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n!)^2}{(2015x)^{2n}}$.

Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}f(x)dx$.

My idea: Let $E \subset(0, \infty)$, and let $f_n(x)=(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n!)^2}{(2015x)^{2n}}$, then

$|f_n(x)|=|(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n!)^2}{(2015x)^{2n}}|\leq \frac{1}{(2n!)^2}{(2015x)^{2n}}$.

Let $M_n=\frac{1}{(2n!)^2}{(2015x)^{2n}}$. By Ratio test, $\sum M_n $ converges.

By W-M test $f_n$ converges uniformly. We know that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ converges uniformly then $f$ is continuous.

I know that if $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is continuous and bounded , then $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}f(x)=f(c)$ for some $c\in (0,\infty)$.

My question is how do I claim $f$ is bounded on $E$? Anyone can suggest me some hints?

Comment: Hint:$$n!=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: You can integrate the given series termwise (assuming the interchange of series and integral is justified). If you mean why is this hint true either employ the definition of the Gamma function or use induction (integration by parts).

Comment: I also think to apply the term by term integration, but the book says $\int_{a}^{b}f dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b}f_n dx$. In this question $x \in (0, \infty)$. Is this result can apply on $(0, \infty)$, instead of $[a,b]$

Comment: Yes but as I said you technically need to justify that this is valid for the case when $b\to\infty$ in the given example (it's not always true).

Comment: Ohk. You mean firstly I show $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,b]$, then apply term by term integration, and then take $b \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @user251257, I think $f(x)\neq cos(2015x)$, because $f(x)=cos(2015x)=1-\frac{1}{2!}(2015x)^{2}+.......$, but $f(x)$ has one more term in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on any compact set, so for any $t > 0$ we have
$$ \int_0^t e^{-x} f(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^t e^{-x} f_n(x) dx. $$
Further, we have
$$ \left| \int_0^t e^{-x} f_n(x) dx \right| \le \frac1{((2n)!)^2} \int_0^t e^{-x} (2015x)^{2n} dx \le \frac{(2n)!}{((2n)!)^2} \frac1{2015} = \frac{1}{(2n)!} \frac1{2015} =: M_n. $$
Finally, as $\sum_n M_n \le \frac e{2015} < \infty$, we have by [Tannery's theoreom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem)
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^t e^{-x} f_n(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t e^{-x} f_n(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x} f_n(x) dx, $$
which can be easily computed.