# How can I (analytically or numerically) integrate the product of exp(-x) and fractionally degreed polynomials?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gamma-function, approximate-integration

Are there any closed form solution to this integral? If not are there any good numerical methods to evaluate it?

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} (x+3)^{2.5} \times (1+x)^{3.5} \times exp(-x) dx$$

I have tried integration by parts and some online integral calculators, but all attempts are failed. Are there any good suggestions?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Gonçalo, thanks for your suggestions, I have tried and that works and I get the final answer! But in addition may I know (1) whether the close form really exists or not and (2) which numerical integration method is the best to use.

Comment: Chances are, they have no closed form solutions except in some special cases. Fractional powers and exponentials aren't friends when it comes to integration

Comment: This may be useful. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758048/how-do-i-evaluate-int-0-inftye-xfxdx?noredirect=1

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

Povided that $\Re(a)>0\land \Re(c)>-1$
$$\int_0^\infty (x+a)^b \, x^c\,e^{-x}\,dx=\Gamma (c+1)\, a^{b+c+1} \,\,U(c+1,b+c+2,a)$$

Assuming that $(a,b,c)$ are positive numbers,
$$\int_0^\infty (x+a)^b \, x^c\,e^{-x}\,dx=\Gamma (c+1)\,\, U(-b,-b-c,a)$$

In both cases appears Kummer's  confluent hypergeometric function. So,a series solution is feasible using the binomial expansion.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (x+3)^{2.5} \, (x+\color{red}{0})^{3.5} \, e^{-x}\, dx=\frac{105 \sqrt{\pi }}{16}\,\, U\left(-\frac{5}{2},-6,3\right)=2070.92$$